# How to open links inside iframe overruling window.open

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe and inside this iframe is a website (not mine so i have no control over that website).

All their links are created like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="window.open('/onlineplayer.php?stream_id=669968', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600,top=200, left=250,resizable=0,scrollbars=1');return(false);">Some Text</a>
```

In my iframe i have sandbox='allow-scripts allow-same-origin' so the links don't open at all. When i ad allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox they open but they open in a new window outside my iframe.

My question is:

Is there any way i could overrule window.open and open links in a new popup but inside my iframe?